# Cómo puedo hacer que esta función me imprima el número mayor de todos los elementos del array?

Tags: javascript

```
const an=[];
let mayor;
function m(){
 console.log(Math.max(an));
}
m(1,3,5);
```

Esta sería la porción del código, usé la función Math.max para que me imprima el mayor de todos los numeros

Answer (score 2):

Primero, `Math.max` no espera como argumento un array de números sino cero o mas números, por lo tanto para usarla debes [expandir el array](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
let an = [1, 3, 5]
console.log(Math.max(...an))
```

Por otro lado, tu código es algo confuso, primero tu array `an` es un array vacío, calcular su valor máximo tiene poco sentido... En cambio llamas a tu función `m` con tres argumentos enteros (que no un array de enteros), pero no defines a tu función para que acepte ningún argumento.

Si quieres que `m` reciba un array como argumento entonces simplemente seria algo como:

```js
const an = [1, 3, 5];

function m(numbers_array) {
  console.log(Math.max(...numbers_array));
}

m(an);
```

Si lo que quieres es que muestre el mayor de un numero indeterminado de parámetros, puedes usar [parámetros rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```js
function m(...numbers) {
  console.log(Math.max(...numbers));
}

m(1, 3, 5);
```